# the following html is not rendered by jinjia2

Tags: javascript, html

I find the following code in layuiadmin framework, but they are not rendered by jinjia2 in flask.

`<script type="text/html" id="buttonTpl">`

```
{{#  if(d.check == true){ }}
<button class="layui-btn layui-btn-xs">已审核</button>
{{#  } else { }}
<button class="layui-btn layui-btn-primary layui-btn-xs">未审核</button>
{{#  } }}
```

How to render it?

Comment: I'm no python expert but that doesn't look like valid jijna syntax see [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not look like a valid jinja2 template.

You can checkout if statement section for the right way.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#if

A valid version should look like this...

```
{% if d.check == true %}
<button class="layui-btn layui-btn-xs">已审核</button>
{% else %}
<button class="layui-btn layui-btn-primary layui-btn-xs">未审核</button>
{% endif %}
```